# How to replace a charachter and change the Scre at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a game program that generate a random number N composed of 8 characters starting by 9. then the user will write a number A starting by 9 too and composed of 8 characters, and he got 8 chances to do that and he start with a Score=100, So if the user number is the same as N the program will finish with saying"well done", if not, the program will A and N, so if a character in A is in the right position in N he will stay at the same place, if the character is correct but it's not in the right place, he will be replaced by "*", and if the character isn't in N he will be replaced by "-". Also the user will start with a Score of 100. for each "*" the score will be minimised by 1 and for each "-" it will be minimised by 2. i tried that code:

```
from random import*
N= "9"+str(randint(1000000,9999999))
G=str(N)

Score=100        
C = 0
Valide = False

while Valide == False and C<=8:                
    A=input("complete number of 8 characters"+'\t'+"9")
    T=str(A)
    if A.isdigit() == True:
        print("")
    while A.isdigit() == False:
        A=input("Terminer le nombre de 8 chiffres"+'\t'+"9")

    while len(A)!=7:
        A=input("complete number of 8 characters"+'\t'+"9")

    if "9"+A==N:
        Valide = True
        print("you got it!")
        print("Score:",Score)
        exit()

    for k in G:
        for v in T:

            if v == k:
                S=v
            elif v in k:
                S=T.replace(str(T.index(v)),"*")
            else:
                S=T.replace(str(T.index(v)),"-")

        if "*" in S:
            Score -=1
        if "-" in S:
            Score -=2

    print ('9'+ S)

    print (Score)
    C += 1

if A==N :
    print("Bravo")
else:
    print("Game Over")
    print("You've reached the maximum number of guesses.")
    print("Score:",Score)
    exit()
```

but in this code the program don't work correctly, also the score get minimised only once and if you enter an 11 characters number for exemple it won't be excuted directly but then if you enter an 8 characters number the first one(11 characters) will be excuted. 
Thank you